# From PHP to iPhone table

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a file named `numbers.php` on my ftp with the following content:

> 1/Brian/Red
>   2/Simon/Blue
>   3/Louise/Red

How do I get that into a table?

I need the table to show:

> Brian
>   Simon
>   Loiuse

in the cells and then when you click on one of the names it takes you to a page with the colour matching the name.

I use this code when I just need to read a single line in a php file and output to textfields:

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://website.com/numbers.php"];
NSData *dataRequest =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: queryString]];
NSString *serverOutput = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataRequest encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
urlTextField.text = serverOutput;
NSArray *splitString = [serverOutput componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
NSString *idOut = [splitString objectAtIndex: 0]; NSString *nameOut = [splitString objectAtIndex: 1]; NSString *colorOut = [splitString objectAtIndex: 2];
idTextField.text = idOut; nameTextField.text = nameOut; colorTextField.text = colorOut;
```

But I am a bit in doubt when it comes to multiple lines and how to get them into my table view. I assume I need to put the lines into an array?

Answer (score 0):

First, I generate plist-Data on the server with the free avaliable CFPropertyList. Why, because it is verry easy to import plist-structures later.

In the app you can import data this way:

```
NSArray * myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  
URLWithString:@"http://url.com/foo.plist"]];
```

you can use NSMutableArray instead when you modifing myArray.

cheers

Comment: Problem is, I am fetching the data from my mysql database with several entries, so I'd have to create hundreds of plist files for each user who logs in.

Comment: no you dont. You can access your plist with a param (plist.php?user=username) then the data will flow back dynamic.